# Validation test in r using for loop to find out mean square error for regressions of degree 1 to 10 repeated 30 times for each regression

Tags: r, validation

I need to run validation test for a dataset with 3500 observations. I split the dataset to trained set and test set 50:50 and wrote the code to calculate mean square error. The thing is I need to do this for the fitted regression of degree 1 to 10 and repeat the process 30 times for each degree of regression. This is where the for loop comes in and I can't seem to do that. Below is my code:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  FYI- including your code as a code snippet (rather than as a screenshot) makes it easier for others to attempt an answer to your question.

Comment: Just a few thoughts: `lapply(1:10, some_function_taking_argument_i_from_1_to_10)` might be a good starting point, so try to learn what `lapply` does. Also note that in your inner loop, you probably want to capture the final result somewhere, e.g. by assigining it to a list or vector etc that has been instantiated before the loop. Last but not least, check out the package `caret`. It takes care of a lot of this stuff for you.